# linq query for finding total leave group by leave type

Tags: c#, linq

i have 1 employee leave table which contain records like this:

```
empid          leave_type         Leave_from    Leave_to           leave_taken              status  
 1            annual leave         3-3-2014     4-3-2014               2                   approved

 1            annual leave         5-3-2014     6-3-2014               2                   approved

 1            sick leave           10-3-2014    11-3-2014              2                   approved

 1            sick leave           12-3-2014    13-3-2014              2                   approved

 1            Casual leave         19-3-2014    20-3-2014              2                   approved

 1            Casual leave         22-3-2014    23-3-2014              2                   approved
```

---

now i want to calculate total leave taken by particular employee by leave type of march month only  whose status is approved like as shown in below:

```
leave_type        leave_taken

   annual leave           4

   sick leave             4

   casual leave           4
```

i have written query like this:

```
var data = (from r in context.emp_leaves
                            where r.Emp_id == empid && r.status == "Approved" 
                            group r by new
                            {
                                r.Emp_id,r.leave_type
                            } into g
                            select new
                            {
                                leave_taken = g.Sum(x => x.leave_taken)
                            });
```

but it is showing wrong output.

can anyone provide me linq query for this???

Comment: i have posted what i have tried

Comment: You updated it later when I saw there was no query

Comment: I think you will have that in data variable

Comment: yer u r right.i didnt see that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are filtering by `Emp_id` you do not need to group on it

```
var data = (from r in context.emp_leaves
            where r.Emp_id == empid && r.status == "Approved" 
            group r by r.leave_type into g
            select new
            {
              leave_type = g.Key,
              leave_taken = g.Sum(x => x.leave_taken)
            });
```